# Magento 2.3.1 - PayPal Payments always show as Suspected Fraud Status

Tags: magento2, paypal, suspected-fraud

we are facing a strange behavior.

We are working with a Magento 2.3.1 version and the PayPal Module, which is pre-installed.

All works well, customers can pay via PayPal but **every** order paid via PayPal gets the status "Suspected Fraud".

We only work with 1 basec currency = EUR.

Does anybody maybe have an idea, how to solve this?

Comment: R u using any third party module with PayPal ?

Comment: No, actually the pre-installed PayPal Express Checkout solution from Magento 2

Comment: I know that one way for orders to be marked as suspected fraud reliably is if there is a mismatch in totals and amounts that are sent to PayPal so it could be a bug in the integration... we've faced this error in Magento 1 many time, the best way to find out is to disable all you custom and third part module, all at once and try.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this. It was simply an option. For Payment Action, instead of "Authoirsation" simply chose "Sale". Then it should work directly.